# Is it possible to divide my Outlook inbox TO me and CC to me?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I need two groups in my Outlook inbox:

- Mails that come directly to me (my email address in mail TO field)  - **more important**
- Mails that are CC or BCC to me - **less important**

Then I can sort my inbox by date. So it populates most recent emails that I should attend. How can I accomplish this separation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up two rules that will filter your mail that way. Here's how to do it in Outlook 2013. (The steps will be similar in other versions of Outlook.)

## To create the "To" rule:

1. Select the **File** tab at the top of the Outlook window
2. Select **Manage Rules & Alerts** button
3. Select **New Rule**
4. Select **Apply rule on messages I receive** (under the *Start from a blank rule* heading)
5. Select **Next**
6. Put a check next to **where my name is in the To box**
7. Select **Next**
8. Put a check next to **mark it as importance**
9. In the lower box of the Rules Wizard (*Step 2*) click on the **importance** link
10. Select **High** or **Medium**, depending on how you want to designate those emails
11. Select **Next**
12. Select **Finish**
13. A notification will display; once you've read it, select **OK**

---

## To create the "Cc/Bcc" rule:

Follow the same steps as above, but substitute the below steps for #6 and #10:

6. Put a check next to **where my name is in the Cc box**

*and*

10. Select **Medium** or **Low**, depending on how you want to designate those emails

---

Once you have set up both rules, select **OK** to exit the Rules and Alerts window.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple outlook rules should do the trick...

`where my name is in the To box` and `where my name is in the Cc box`, combined with `move it to the specified folder`.